# Discrepancy between TTFB and ALB TargetResponseTime

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm wondering if someone can give me some advice.

We've decided to move to our NextJS AWS recently (ECS Fargate) and I'm noticing a high TTFB when compared with our current platform.

I've looked into the ALB logs and there seems to be a massive discrepancy between the reported TargetResponseTime (around 1.3secs) and the TTFB (around 2.5secs).

Could this be some sort of latency in the load balancer? If so how would I go about debugging this?

The application is the same on both hosting providers and I did a traceroute to ensure it wasn't network latency from me to the apps (in fact it was quicker to get to AWS).